# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Relationship Issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, relationship, eloquent

I need to clear my doubt about Eloquent Relationships. I have 2 models User (which comes with Laravel) and Other is Role which I created.
in migration, I added role_id as an additional column as I want every user must have a role now I want to retrieve a user role based on user's id so, I created a public function named roles inside the User Model.

```
    public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
```

now when i try to run the query like this.

```
  App\User::find(1)->roles;
```

it won't return any result, just empty screen but when I change it to

```
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
```

after that i run code

```
  App\User::find(1)->role;
```

now it returns the exact row where the user with id 1 has a proper role. it's confusing why with the roles() function it's not working but with the role() function it's working.

Sorry, If this question is already posted you can redirect me to that question.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the foreign key

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'role_id');
}
```

However, calling it role() is more accurate, since your are assuming that a User can only have one role.

Comment: yes, I know that each user has one role but my question is why roles() didn't work but role() works after you answer and putting second argument role_id in roles() function it worked as well. but what is the logic behind this?

Comment: Eloquent, by default will look for the fk : roles_id